# JQuery Refresh DIV with new URL from form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form with one text box that is part of a div tag.  I want it to change the contents of that div tag to another page based on the contents of a textbox in a php GET request.

for example if you type hell into the textbox it will load goto.php?location=hell into the div.

so far this is the code i have below, and due to it being my first time with jquery sucks more than a hoover vacuum cleaner.

```
<div id="city"></div>
<form name="goto" action="/"> 
<input type="text" id="city">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="New City" /> 
</form>
<script>
  /* attach a submit handler to the form */
  $("#goto").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault(); 

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        city = $form.find( 'input[name="city"]' ).val(),

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $('currentwxdiv').load('http://www.jquerynoob.bomb/hell.php?location=' + city);

  });
</script>
```

Currently instead up updating the contents of the div it reloads the entire page in the browser and then appends it with ?submit=New+City

**UPDATE**  This is what I have now and its still doing the full page refresh with the appended  ?submit=New+City

```
<script>
  /* attach a submit handler to the form */
  $$('form[name="changewx"]').submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault(); 

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        city = $('#city').val()

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $('#currentwxdiv').load('http://api.mesodiscussion.com/?location=' + city);

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Where does the form `changewx` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created your form like this:

```
<form name="goto" action="/">
```

But the selector only matches the element with an id `goto`. So it should be:

```
$('form[name="goto"]').submit(function(event) {
```

You also made a mistake the other way around:

```
$form.find( 'input[name="city"]' ).val()
```

Should be:

```
$('#city').val()
```

Another thing:

```
$('currentwxdiv') // this matches a tag called currentwxdiv
```

Should be:

```
$('.currentwxdiv') // for element with class currentwxdiv, or $('#currentwxdiv') to match based on id
```

And instead of doing `e.stopPropagation();` you should do `return false;` at the end of the function.

Comment: I changed that... but instead of updating the div contents it reloads the entire page in the browser and appends the URL with ?submit=New+City

Comment: @ZacharyLassiter Please see my updated answer. I spotted another thing

Comment: still having the same problem.... added return false; however I could not find the e.stopPropagation() to replace it with.

Comment: What is the `changewx` in your edited question? Why do you have two dollar signs in front of it? `$$`

Comment: i changed the form name to more reflect what im doing.  the form name is changewx... i removed the double dollar sign.  Now when clicking the button it does nothing.  The page stays as is.